# Detecting markers in image to use for perspective transform in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

I've been spending a few evenings tinkering with OpenCV. I'm working on a small project that does some analysis on content within a page. I'd like to do a perspective transform of the page to line and fit the entire screen first. However, I can't depend that people will be holding the paper on a different coloured background, or back enough to fit the entire page boundaries.

So I thought of adding markers on opposite corners of the page to track, get their positions, and do a warp transform with them. Here is the sample image of the corner-markers I am trying to detect:[image: sample image]

What is the best approach for this? I'm mainly looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: For a warp you'll need 4 points! If you want to stay with those border-corners, try houghLinesP but I think it might be not perfect markers.

Comment: I was thinking just interchanging the x and y of the 2 points to get my 3rd and 4th. But that probably won't work for rotated images unless I extend the line vectors and have them intersect. @Micka I've used houghLinesP a little before, any suggestions with using it in this context and avoiding any other lines that may appear in the image?

Comment: Only thing you can hope for those markers is that no other lines intersect by 90 degrees. You cant just interchange to get 2 more points because of perspective distortion.

Answer (score 1):

Cute idea! As others have noted, two points are not enough, but your markers define four lines, and those are enough.

If you can reliably detect edges on the line segments forming your markers, you can fit lines to them and then either directly compute the line homography (and then inverse-transpose it to convert it to a point homography), or intersect the lines in pairs to get four independent corners, and then compute the point homography on them.

Some experimentation may be needed to reliably detect your markers. You may want to consider using template matching.

Comment: Any suggestions in making sure the lines HoughLinesP returns correspond to those on the corners and not from within the page's contents? I'll look more into this line/point homography. Up until now I've just been doing a warp transformation once I've found the 4 vertices.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can first get the **first** black pixel in the image and the
   **last** black pixel in the image after applying binary threshold to it. You will obtain 2 points that are **diagonal** to each other.
2. Using these two points you can obtain the **other** diagonal points
   using `img.shape` property.
3. Now you have 4 points, after which you can perform **warp transform**.